# Is ok to say 'go right'? Meaning turn right?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Is that ok to say `go right` meaning turn right? Or I have to say only `go to the right`?

Comment: In my English book is "go to the right". But I thought that go right is "better"

Comment: so I better not to use "go right" when talking about direction etc...

Answer (score 4):

"Go right at the traffic lights" is entirely idiomatic, meaning *turn right*. "Go to the right" sounds unusual to me as a native British English speaker.

"Move to the right" is common. In terms of driving it could mean *change lanes*<sup>+</sup>, in other situations it could just mean *you're in my way, there's space to the right, move into it*.

---

*<sup>+My thanks to David Garner</sup>*

Comment: and what about "go right" = "turn right"?

Comment: Did you read my first sentence?

Comment: Yes, still sleeping or something ...

Comment: @AndyT "move to the right" suggest a lane-change, rather than a turn, to me.

Comment: @DavidGarner - Thanks, I hadn't thought of that. I was just thinking of physically moving out of someone's way. Updated to cover both.